# Particle System bake fine individually, but mess up when more than one is baked

Tags: particles, bezier-curves, baking

see gif below. Have different emitter/curve pairs in different collections, with the curves set to act as paths for the particles of the emitters. I have the Particle Properties > Render > Render As set to "Path".

Here are the steps I show in the gif:

1. Bake the particle system on each emitter individually, deleting all bakes in between.
2. Bake one emitter, then another, without deleting bakes in between. This is where the problem happens.

I don't know if this is relevent, but I tried using the "Disk Cache" then Bake, and the program crashed (not shown).
[image]

using blender 2.92.0

Comment: I found a temporary fix by checking "external" in the cache section and then unchecking it, alt+dragging. idk how it works but it does. mess still happens if I press play after though.

Comment: This site is for helping with working in Blender. I'm pretty sure the program crashing is no intended functionality, so this is probably a bug and should be reported (_Help_ > _Report a Bug_). On this site we are no Blender developers or in any way affiliated with the software so we cannot help with bug fixes, so this question is considered offtopic here. Apart from that, 2.92 is an older version and it might well be that this bug is no longer present in newer versions.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann the crashing was not main issue, it was just a detail I included in case it was relevant. I'll edit it out. The issue I'm asking about is the baking behavior described, and shown in the gif. I'm trying to learn if there's something I might be misunderstanding about the cache/baking functionality, or if that behavior is unintended/a bug . I'll update the program soon and update the question if anything changes.